# How to add Announcements to page

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part

I' ve added an Announcement List to my Site.  However, I can't seem to add it to a page - there is no web part listed that I can use.  I have the same issue with Project tasks.  I'm using Sharepoint with Office 365.  Am I missing something or is there no web part for Announcements or project tasks?    [image: webpart listing]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern pages seem not to have WebPart for Annoucements. Custom List Web Part also does not support Announcements and it seems that you cannot directly embed Announcements within custom modern page. What MS proposes is to use News webpart. They are also creating modern look for Announcements list (it will not solve your problem though).

Please find more details [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Blog/Improving-SharePoint-Links-and-Announcements-lists/ba-p/92379)

Comment: Thanks very much.  Link you provided helped get an understanding that Modern look is still in development.  Causing me a bit of confusion as I'm dipping back into Sharepoint after not using it for a few years - expected just to be able to pick it up again.  Wrong!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the list preview web part to only display custom lists.  But If you set allow management of content types (under advanced in list settings) to yes - you can add the announcement content type (under "Add from existing site content types").

Then change new button order default content type to Announcements first (but keep items checked).  Now the list should appear when you add the list preview web part.  Use title and body columns in the view

Its not perfect but it does emulate enough of the Announcement web part to work

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible with the Highlighted Content Webpart.
Configuration:

- Source: this site
- Type: all
- Documenttype: all
- Filter:

  - Managed property: *ContentType* equal to *Announcement*

You can't however view the content of the announcement itself in the webpart. It only shows the title and author, not the message itself.